# Dar formato a varios DIV dependiendo de valores ocultos

Tags: javascript, html, css, script

Necesito ayuda para dar formato a unos DIV dependiendo del valor que se encuentre dentro de una tabla, hasta ahora he podido hacer que se le de formato a un solo DIV pero el segundo ya no sigue la condición

```js
function cargar() {
    var celdas = document.getElementById("target").getElementsByTagName("p");
    for(var i=0; i<celdas.length; i++) {
        if(celdas.item(i).textContent >=.906 && celdas.item(i).textContent <.9996) {
            document.getElementById("color").style.background = "#FFFF00";
        }
        if(celdas.item(i).textContent >=.9996) {
            document.getElementById("color").style.background= "#007A00";
        }
        if(celdas.item(i).textContent <.906) {
            document.getElementById("color").style.background = "#F00";
        }
    }
}

window.onload = cargar;
```

```html
<table id="target">
  <tr>
      <td>1<p style="display: none">.905</p><div id="color"></div></td>
      <td>.906<p style="display: none">.9905</p><div id="color"></div></td>
      <td>3<p style="display: none">.995</p><div id="color"></div></td>
      <td>.96<p style="display: none">.905</p><div id="color"></div></td>
      <td>.1506<p style="display: none">.95</p><div id="color"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Este es el código que estoy utilizando, agradecería cualquier ayuda. Muchas gracias

Comment: El atributo id ha de ser único, si usas `id="color"` para todos los div, `getElementById` siempre te devolverá el primero que encuentre

Comment: Que otro atributo le puedo agregar para que use todos? Intente con class="color" y agregar getElementByClassName y no me funcionó

Comment: Para que funcione el selector de clase, debes utilizar `getElementsByClassName`. La diferencia está en `Element` por `Elements` ya que puede encontrar más de uno. En vez de devolver el elemento, te devuelve un `array` con los elementos encontrados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
function cargar(){
 // con querySelectorAll() obtenemos todos los elementos p dentro de #target
 // con nextSibling seleccionamos el elemento siguiente del tag (p) o sea div#color
    for(let x of document.querySelectorAll("#target p")){

        if(x.textContent >=.906 && x.textContent <.9996)
            x.nextSibling.style.background = "#FFFF00";
        if(x.textContent >=.9996)
            x.nextSibling.style.background= "#007A00";

        if(x.textContent <.906)
            x.nextSibling.style.background = "#F00";
    }
}

window.onload = cargar;
```

```css
#target div{
width:20px;
height:20px;
}
```

```html
<table id="target">
      <tr>
          <td>1<p style="display: none">.905</p><div></div></td>
          <td>.906<p style="display: none">.9905</p><div></div></td>
          <td>3<p style="display: none">.995</p><div></div></td>
          <td>.96<p style="display: none">.905</p><div></div></td>
          <td>.1506<p style="display: none">.95</p><div></div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Funciona correctamente

Comment: @JSilvermask de nada para ello es la comunidad.